# Differences BW Facebook Login and FBSDKLoginKit Pod and which one to use?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I was trying to integrate **facebook login** in my iOS app. I am reading the official docs for this purpose.

On this [getting started link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started). Documentation say to use the following pods

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

So i understood that i have to use pod `FacebookLogin` and that's it.,

> BUT

On this [iOS login Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) page, Docs say to use

```
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

1. I am totally confused about which one to use.
2. What's the difference between the two?

---

**Note**: I just want to perform facebook login in my app and nothing else.

Comment: I recommend Firebase authentication instead, which Google is strongly encouraging going forward and it includes Facebook. Although the above answers also work. Google's docs are better than the others when it comes to authentication, and in most cases you have more than one authentication as required by Apple, so this can get you all of that with less effort. Plus all the methods get updated frequently and it can be hard to keep up to date. I hated the recoding, but it's worth it and simpler and cleaner in the end.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJ. 
So,  i am not using firebase in my project for anything. So you are saying to use firebase for authentication only?

Comment: Yes. I was in the same boat. Google is pushing Firebase for authentication as the primary method as of just about a month ago. Firebase can be used for just authentication. I had already coded five other authentication procedures into my project so I wasn't keen on switching, but the advantage is that you get Facebook, Twitter, Email/Password, and Google among others very easily, and via pods. The documentation is clear. And inevitably they will be upgraded regularly. Both Facebook's and Twitter's API changed recently for example. Facebook hints it will drop the API you're using.

Comment: But i have to integrate my mobile app with website. My backend Developers are using Django REST framework with PostGres. So, after authentication, i have to send data to backend where it will be processed and i should get a response. 

So there won't be any problems in my scenario. ?

Comment: We have a similar situation. Firebase uses the current Facebook pods and figures out automatically what is required. You will get back valid access tokens that you can use in other methods. Firebase is just a wrapper that simplifies it, and promises forwarded compatibility. Facebook is not currently promising forward compatibility as it comes up with a new API and is faced with privacy issues. Firebase seems to be more of a label than an entire framework. We only use the authentication code. This seems to be separate and discrete from other Firebase services.

Comment: @DavidJ: Thank you very much for useful insights about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of November 2019 the standalone swift SDK [has been deprecated](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/blob/master/Announcement.md) in favor of a single repository.

Therefore, it you should be using `FBSDKCoreKit`, `FBSDKShareKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` **with Cocoapods**.

> We plan on archiving this repo on November 1, 2019. This gives users one month to follow the instructions below for migrating to the new source code location. At this time we will also **deprecate the CocoaPods FacebookCore, FacebookLogin, and FacebookShare**.

[The current documentation](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) is a little bit confusing, as this section is actually referring to **Swift Package Manager**, not Cocoapods.

> For projects that include Swift, use 'FacebookCore', 'FacebookLogin', and 'FacebookShare'
>
> For projects that do not include Swift, use 'FBSDKCoreKit' 'FBSDKLoginKit' and 'FBSDKShareKit'

Comment: In addition, if you _are_ using Swift, _but not_ Swift Package Manager (SPM) (e.g. you are using CocoaPods instead), you should be using `FBSDKCoreKit` as well. Source, Facebook docs itself. Admittedly, it is worded very poorly by them. So read carefully if you want to confirm for yourself:
- https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/blob/master/MigrationGuide.md
- https://cocoapods.org/pods/FacebookSDK

Answer (score 11):

If you are using swift then use 'FacebookCore' and FacebookLogin'.
For objective C use 'FBSDKLoginKit'.
But if you see internally in podfile, they use objective C code via bridging.

Comment: Got it. There are separate pods for Swift and Objc. right. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that Swift SDK is deprecated. see @ arsenius's answer below

Answer (score 6):

You should use below pods for Login with Facebook using Swift

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

Because in their official documentation's guideline for integrating Facebook Login in Swift they have mentioned those pods, so there may be some difference which they made for Swift and that's why they provide separate pods. You can assume `pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'` is for Objective-C because they shown Objective-C sample code on that page. Otherwise officially they haven't made any notes or declaration about these differences.

Comment: Got it. There are separate pods for Swift and Objc. right. Thanks.